# Обязательно ли использовать мьютекс перед cond_var.notify()?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

У меня несколько вопросов.
1) `std::condition_variable` везде рассматривается как средство синхронизации доступа к данным. Поэтому примеры использования обычно выглядят как-то так:

```
void put(const T &val) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mtx);
  m_Value = val;
  m_CondVar.notify_one();
}
T get() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mtx); 
  m_CondVar.wait(lock);
  return m_Value;
}
```

Это понятно. Но что если мне не нужно передавать данные, а нужно только разбудить ожидающий поток (если он есть) - могу я в данном случае НЕ использовать мьютекс?

```
void put() {
  m_CondVar.notify_one();
}
```

В документации про это вроде бы не написано. В документации к `pthread_cond_signal` есть расплывчатое:

> The pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() functions may be
>   called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that
>   threads calling pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() have
>   associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if
>   predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be
>   locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or
>   pthread_cond_signal().

что не удается трактовать однозначно.
Цель - микрооптимизация, меньше мьютексов, меньше потенциального context switching.

2) какая стоимость у `m_CondVar.notify_one();` ? Это будет обычный syscall ?

3) может быть вы знаете более легкий способ нотификации (без передачи сообщения или с передачей, неважно) одного потока из другого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас нет возможности не использовать мьютекс при ожидании на `std::condition_variable`, потому что такого API не предусмотрено. Но даже если бы такое было, выход из `wait` не всегда значит, что был получен сигнал через `notify_one`. Есть такое понятие как «spurious wake up», из-за которого возможен подобный выход из `wait`. Поэтому правильно иметь разделённую переменную (флаг), который будет выставляться на стороне уведомляющего, и проверяться на стороне уведомляемого. Этот флаг можно охранять мьютексом, либо же использовать атомарный объект. Но раз API уже заставляет нас использовать мьютекс, то использование его вполне оправдано.

Что касается цены и прочего: проверяйте на практике, стандартом такие вещи не регламентируются. Лучшего способа разбудить поток в стандартном C++ не существует. А так можно использовать разные примитивы, но суть от этого никак не изменится: есть какой-то объект и на нём ждём.

Comment: get() без мьютекса не получится, но вопрос - можно ли делать put() без мьютекса?

Comment: @o2gy, API этого не запрещает. Но я описал почему это нежелательно.

Comment: То есть, если «spurious wake up» не считать проблемой, то все ок - можно без мьютекса, верно?

Comment: @o2gy, для кода «в вакууме» я других проблем не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе в ответе @ixSci все верно, но мало подробностей. Я немного покопался в вопросе и хотел бы дополнить.

> 1) Но что если мне не нужно передавать данные, а нужно только разбудить ожидающий поток (если он есть) - могу я в данном случае НЕ использовать мьютекс?

Прямой ответ на этот вопрос - **да, можно**. В примерах на cppreference [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) и [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) - именно так и делают. Там вообще все вызовы `notify_one()/notify_all()` делаются НЕ под мьютексом.
Что касается «spurious wake up» - стандарт POSIX прямо говорит:

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() functions may occur. Since the return from pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

Таким образом, действительно, единственный корректный способ использовать condition_variable предполагает наличие условий, которые определяют: изменилось ли что-либо в памяти процесса или нет, и которые должны быть перепроверены после пробуждения потока из `cv.wait()`.

Чтобы обеспечить указанную корректность, необходимо и достаточно соблюсти следующее правило: *update данных в потоке T1 и check-and-wait на тех же данных в потоке T2 - должны быть выполнены под одной и той же критической секцией.*

`notify()` при этом можно выполнять как в той же критической секции, так и вне ее.
Более того, в документации к [notify_one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) даже говорится о том, что удержание блокировки во время вызова `notify()` - это пессимизация в том смысле, что если бы блокировка во время этого вызова была бы уже снята, то тогда ожидающий на `wait()` поток точно смог бы захватить мьютекс и не законтекстсвитчится. Так что в некоторых случаях можно было бы даже рекомендовать снимать блокировку перед вызовом `notify()`. Однако я накидал [бенчмарк](https://github.com/o2gy84/misc/tree/master/benchmark/condvar_vs_mutex) и оказалось, что на моей виртуалке данный трюк почему-то значительно замедляет программу. Так что надо тестировать.

PS: не получится реализовать check-and-wait с помощью atomic типов. да, сами по себе `atomic.load()` и `cv.wait()` - атомарны, но их последовательность - нет, а в данном случае требуется именно "атомарность" проверки предиката и вызова `cv.wait()` в последовательности.

PPS: отдельный интересный момент связан с самим понятием «spurious wake-up», что это такое. "spurious wake-up" - это поведение, явно определяемое стандартом POSIX, в linux оно может быть связано с тем, что блокирующий syscall должен быть прерван в случае, если процесс получает сигнал. Вот [тут](http://blog.vladimirprus.com/2005/07/spurious-wakeups.html) я нашел довольно интересный пост на эту тему.

> 2) какая стоимость у `m_CondVar.notify_one()`; ? Это будет обычный syscall ?

На linux это syscall в подсистему `futex`, что в общем-то недешево. В `strace` оно выглядит вот так:

```
futex(0x6063ac, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x6063a8, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1})
```

В том же [бенчмарке](https://github.com/o2gy84/misc/tree/master/benchmark/condvar_vs_mutex) я попробовал сравнить `notify()` с соседними сисколлами, у меня получилось, что `notify()` стоит примерно столько же, сколько и блокировка мьютекса.

> 3) может быть вы знаете более легкий способ нотификации (без передачи сообщения или с передачей, неважно) одного потока из другого?

Я решил протестировать и сравнить между собой следующие способы:

- mutex + condvar
- semaphore
- [fdevent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)
- [линуксовые posix-очереди](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_open)

Результат бенчмарка [тут](https://github.com/o2gy84/misc/tree/master/benchmark/condvar_vs_fdevent).
Семафоры и связка mutex + condvar работают примерно одинаково быстро (видимо внутри у них одна реализация через futex), fdevent - примерно в 2 раза медленнее, mq_queue - уже сильно медленнее.
Так что, получается, да - самый быстрый способ нотификации между потоками - это mutex + condvar.